# How are unique indexes handled during simultaneous updates in transactions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to understand how some code with a transaction will work if run by multiple threads. There is a unique 5 character ID that needs to be inserted per record and must be unique for each "job" which is checked by a unique index.

We currently have code that is single threaded and catches duplicate errors, creates a new random ID and tries again. However we are considering moving the ID creation to a later step of processing which is multiple threaded. There is also code in the transaction that uses the random ID but we want to be sure it has the ID that went into the record and that if the code at the end of the transaction fails that the record update does not occur.

What I am trying to understand is if the transaction can only fail when the update query is run and if another error is thrown by the additional code, or if it could possibly fail on commit after the additional code has run.

Here is the code outline....

```
until transaction completes successfully
    try
        begin transaction
            create randomid
            update an existing record with randomid
            do something that should only be done once
        commit transaction
    catch duplicate id error
```

I have tried some tests that didn't show a problem but not sure if my tests were sufficient so would like to better understand what would be going on in this situation.

Also, I assume the update queries can't happen in parallel but from my testing it appears that the additional code does. Is that always the case or does it depend on other considerations?

Comment: What is the transaction isolation level that you're using?

Comment: Default which appears that it should be Read Committed. I am assuming from my tests that since only an update is occurring that other transactions/update code in other threads won't be held up, but let me know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique index on a column and you update this column, SQL Server will put a lock on the index (key range). This will prevent all other processes from updating the same record. They will have to wait for the lock to be released and will be blocked until that time. Once the lock is released, the unique index will prevent them from updating the table.

As other processes have to wait, depending on your timeout setting and the length of the execution, they may time out. You may wish to handle that in addition to handling duplicate exception.

If your processes try to insert different values into the column with the unique index, that may happen in parallel, depending on other locks on the table.